# angularjs http.get web service call is not working for particular url

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get a json object from a specific url, it is not working for some reason. However same code works fine with different url. In the code below  if I use 'restcountries' url it works fine, and it doesnt't work for 'wingerweb***'

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core"
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CountryService{
   //endpoint_url:String = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/region/oceania";
     endpoint_url:String = "http://cors.io/?u=http://wingerweb.azurewebsites.net/WingerApp/rest/menuitems/1";
    constructor(http: Http){
        this.http = http;
    }
    getCountriesByRegion (region:String){
        return this.http.get(this.endpoint_url)
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .do(data => console.log(data))
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError (error: Response) {
    console.log('here');
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try encoding URL before get?

For example,

```
endpoint_url:String = "http://cors.io/?u=" + 
   encodeURIComponent("http://wingerweb.azurewebsites.net/WingerApp/rest/menuitems/1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did and getting below error " SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data "

Comment: I had used the same url before with 'cors' appended and was working fine. And for some reason, I couldn't use 'http://wingerweb.azurewebsites.net/WingerApp/rest/menuitems/1' directly. It is a valid url and returns json object

Comment: here is the plunk for source code https://plnkr.co/edit/GijNlncY2sPFVqANM14v?p=preview